# colouring the road with different colours on map

Tags: c#, image-processing, emgucv

I'm creating a simple application in C# and I would like to be able to colour the roads on a map with different colours, a road map, not a satellite image. As you can see in the image below.
Do you know of any API or sample that would meet my needs? Thanks in advance.

[image]